# RTC shield with LCD and Keypad

Tags: sd-card, rtc, datalogging

I am having issues with a code that I have been modifying.
I can change the TIME, and DATE from a keypad, and see the data on the serial monitor, but it is not recording on the SD Card. Anyone that could help me. Thank you.

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>                     
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>    
#include <Keypad.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4)

RTC_DS3231 rtc;
DateTime   now;

const byte ROWS = 4;
 const byte COLS = 4;
 char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
 {'1','2','3','A'},
 {'4','5','6','B'},
 {'7','8','9','C'},
 {'*','0','#','D'}
 };

 byte rowPINS[ROWS] = {10,9,8,7}; 
 byte colPINS[COLS] = {6,5,4,11}; 

 int i1,i2,i3,i4;
 char c1,c2,c3,c4;
 char keypressed;
  
 Keypad myKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys),rowPINS,colPINS, ROWS, COLS);

#define DS18B20_PIN   A3


File dataLog;
boolean sd_ok = 0;

void setup()
{

  rtc.begin();          // initialize RTC chip
  
  lcd.init();     // initialize LCD module
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);  // move cursor to column 0, row 3 (last row)
  lcd.print("Temp:");

// open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

// initialize the SD card
  if ( !SD.begin() )
    Serial.println(F("initialization failed!"));  // initialization error
else {   // initialization OK
    sd_ok = 1;
    Serial.println(F("initialization done."));
    if( SD.exists("Log.txt") == 0 )   // test if file with name 'Log.txt' already exists
    {  // create a text file named 'Log.txt'
      Serial.print("\r\nCreate 'Log.txt' file ... ");
      dataLog = SD.open("Log.txt", FILE_WRITE);   // create (&open) file Log.txt
      if(dataLog) {                               // if the file opened okay, write to it:
        Serial.println(F("OK"));
        // write some texts to 'Log.txt' file
        dataLog.println("    DATE    |    TIME  | TEMPERATURE");
        dataLog.println("(dd-mm-yyyy)|(hh:mm:ss)|");
        dataLog.close();   // close the file
      }
      else
        Serial.println(F("error creating file."));
    }
  }
   Serial.println(F("\r\n    DATE    |    TIME  | TEMPERATURE"));
   Serial.println(F("(dd-mm-yyyy)|(hh:mm:ss)|"));   
}

// main loop
void loop()
{
  now = rtc.now();  // read current time and date from the RTC chip
  RTC_display();    // display time & calendar
 
  while(keypressed == NO_KEY){ 

  
  keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();


  now = rtc.now();  // read current time and date from the RTC chip
  RTC_display();    // display time & calendar
  
  
static byte p_second;
  if( (now.second()-1==0) ||  (now.second() % 5 == 0) && (p_second != now.second()) )
  {   // read & print temperature value from sensor every 10 seconds
    unsigned int ds18b20_temp;
    char buffer1[12], buffer2[26];
    bool sensor_ok = 0;
    
    p_second = now.second();
    if( ds18b20_read(&ds18b20_temp) )
    {
      sensor_ok = 1;
      if (ds18b20_temp & 0x8000)           // if temperature < 0
      {
        ds18b20_temp = ~ds18b20_temp + 1;  // change temperature value to positive form
        sprintf(buffer1, "-%02u.%04u%cC", (ds18b20_temp/16) % 100, (ds18b20_temp & 0x0F) * 625, 223);
      }
      else
      {      // otherwise (temperature >= 0)
        if (ds18b20_temp/16 >= 100)          // if temperature >= 100.0 °C
          sprintf(buffer1, "%03u.%04u%cC", ds18b20_temp/16, (ds18b20_temp & 0x0F) * 625, 223);
        else      // otherwise ( 0 <= temperature < 100.0)
          sprintf(buffer1, " %02u.%04u%cC", ds18b20_temp/16, (ds18b20_temp & 0x0F) * 625, 223);
      }
    }
    else
      sprintf(buffer1, "   ERROR  ");
 
    lcd.setCursor(5, 3);
    lcd.print(buffer1);
 
    sprintf( buffer2, " %02u-%02u-%04u | %02u:%02u:%02u | ", now.day(), now.month(), now.year(),
                      now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second() );
    if(sensor_ok) {
      buffer1[8] = 194;   // put degree symbol
      buffer1[9] = 176;
      buffer1[10] = 'C';  // put 'C' letter
      buffer1[11] = '\0'; // put string terminator
    }
    // print data on PC serial monitor
    Serial.print(buffer2);
    Serial.println(buffer1);
    // write data to SD card
    if(sd_ok)
    {  // if the SD card was successfully initialized
      // open Log.txt file with write permission
      dataLog = SD.open("Log.txt", FILE_WRITE);
      dataLog.print( buffer2 );
      dataLog.println( buffer1 );
      dataLog.close();   // close the file
    }
 
  }
 
  delay(100);   // wait 100ms

  }  
 
  
if (keypressed == '*') 
             {
              lcd.clear();
              lcd.print("     Setup");
             delay(1000);
              lcd.clear();
              lcd.print("Setup year");
             
             char keypressed2 = myKeypad.waitForKey();  
                    if (keypressed2 != NO_KEY && keypressed2 !='*' && keypressed2 !='#' && keypressed2 !='A' && keypressed2 !='B' && keypressed2 !='C' && keypressed2 !='D' )
                      {
                       c1 = keypressed2;
                       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
                       lcd.print(c1);
                       }
                 char      keypressed3 = myKeypad.waitForKey();
                    if (keypressed3 != NO_KEY && keypressed3 !='*' && keypressed3 !='#' && keypressed3 !='A' && keypressed3 !='B' && keypressed3 !='C' && keypressed3 !='D' )
                      {
                       c2 = keypressed3;
                       lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
                       lcd.print(c2);
                       }
                   char  keypressed4 = myKeypad.waitForKey();
                   if (keypressed4 != NO_KEY && keypressed4 !='*' && keypressed4 !='#' && keypressed4 !='A' && keypressed4 !='B' && keypressed4 !='C' && keypressed4 !='D' )
                      {
                       c3 = keypressed4;
                       lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
                       lcd.print(c3);
                       }
                   char   keypressed5 = myKeypad.waitForKey();
                   if (keypressed5 != NO_KEY && keypressed5 !='*' && keypressed5 !='#' && keypressed5 !='A' && keypressed5 !='B' && keypressed5 !='C' && keypressed5 !='D' )
                      {
                       c4 = keypressed5;
                       lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
                       lcd.print(c4);
                       }

                     i1=(c1-48)*1000;        //the keys pressed are stored into chars I convert them to int then i did some multiplication to get the code as an int of xxxx
                     i2=(c2-48)*100;
                     i3=(c3-48)*10;
                     i4=c4-48;
                     int N_year=i1+i2+i3+i4;
                   delay(500);
                     lcd.clear();
                     lcd.print("Setup month");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                     char keypressed6 = myKeypad.waitForKey();  // here all programs are stopped until you enter the four digits then it gets compared to the code above
                    if (keypressed6 != NO_KEY && keypressed6 !='*' && keypressed6 !='#' && keypressed6 !='A' && keypressed6 !='B' && keypressed6 !='C' && keypressed6 !='D' )
                      {
                       c1 = keypressed6;
                       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
                       lcd.print(c1);
                       }
                    char   keypressed7 = myKeypad.waitForKey();
                    if (keypressed7 != NO_KEY && keypressed7 !='*' && keypressed7 !='#' && keypressed7 !='A' && keypressed7 !='B' && keypressed7 !='C' && keypressed7 !='D' )
                      {
                       c2 = keypressed7;
                       lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
                       lcd.print(c2);
                       }


                     i1=(c1-48)*10;
                     i2=c2-48;
                    int N_month=i1+i2;
                     delay(500);

                     lcd.clear();
                     lcd.print("Setup Day");

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                    
                      char keypressed8 = myKeypad.waitForKey();  // here all programs are stopped until you enter the four digits then it gets compared to the code above
                    if (keypressed8 != NO_KEY && keypressed8 !='*' && keypressed8 !='#' && keypressed8 !='A' && keypressed8 !='B' && keypressed8 !='C' && keypressed8 !='D' )
                      {
                        c1 = keypressed8;
                       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
                       lcd.print(c1);
                       }
                      char keypressed9 = myKeypad.waitForKey();
                    if (keypressed9 != NO_KEY && keypressed9 !='*' && keypressed9 !='#' && keypressed9 !='A' && keypressed9 !='B' && keypressed9 !='C' && keypressed9 !='D' )
                      {
                        c2 = keypressed9;
                       lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
                       lcd.print(c2);
                       }


                     i1=(c1-48)*10;
                     i2=c2-48;
                    int N_day=i1+i2;
                    delay(500);
                     lcd.clear();
                     lcd.print("Setup hour");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////:                     
                     char keypressed10 = myKeypad.waitForKey();  // here all programs are stopped until you enter the four digits then it gets compared to the code above
                    if (keypressed10 != NO_KEY && keypressed10 !='*' && keypressed10 !='#' && keypressed10 !='A' && keypressed10 !='B' && keypressed10 !='C' && keypressed10 !='D' )
                      {
                       c1 = keypressed10;
                       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
                       lcd.print(c1);
                       }
                    char   keypressed11 = myKeypad.waitForKey();
                    if (keypressed11 != NO_KEY && keypressed11 !='*' && keypressed11 !='#' && keypressed11 !='A' && keypressed11 !='B' && keypressed11 !='C' && keypressed11 !='D' )
                      {
                        c2 = keypressed11;
                       lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
                       lcd.print(c2);
                       }


                     i1=(c1-48)*10;
                     i2=c2-48;
                    int N_hour=i1+i2;
                    delay(500);
                     lcd.clear();
                     lcd.print("Setup minutes");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////:
                    char keypressed12 = myKeypad.waitForKey();  // here all programs are stopped until you enter the four digits then it gets compared to the code above
                    if (keypressed12 != NO_KEY && keypressed12 !='*' && keypressed12 !='#' && keypressed12 !='A' && keypressed12 !='B' && keypressed12 !='C' && keypressed12 !='D' )
                      {
                        c1 = keypressed12;
                       lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
                       lcd.print(c1);
                       }
                   char    keypressed13 = myKeypad.waitForKey();
                    if (keypressed13 != NO_KEY && keypressed13 !='*' && keypressed13 !='#' && keypressed13 !='A' && keypressed13 !='B' && keypressed13 !='C' && keypressed13 !='D' )
                      {
                        c2 = keypressed13;
                       lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
                       lcd.print(c2);
                       }


                     i1=(c1-48)*10;
                     i2=c2-48;
                    int N_minutes=i1+i2;
                    delay(500);
                     lcd.clear();

                     
                  rtc.adjust(DateTime(N_year, N_month, N_day, N_hour, N_minutes, 0));
                  
                  RTC_display();
                  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);  // move cursor to column 0, row 3 (last row)
                  lcd.print("Temp:");
                  
                  //myRTC.setDS1302Time(22, N_minutes, N_hour, 1, N_day, N_month, N_year); //once we're done setting the date and time we transfer to values to the RTC module
                                                                                           //the 22 stands for seconds you can add a setup for it too if you want
                                                                                           //the 1 stands for day of the week, as long I don't show it on the screen I don't change it
                    keypressed=NO_KEY; //the "*" key is stored in "keypressed" so I remove that value from it otherwise it will get me in the setup again
              }

}


//////////////////////////////////////// RTC functions ////////////////////////////////////////
void RTC_display()
{
  char _buffer[17];
  char dow_matrix[7][10] = {" SUNDAY  ", " MONDAY  ", " TUESDAY ", "WEDNESDAY",
                             "THURSDAY ", " FRIDAY  ", "SATURDAY "};
  lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
  lcd.print( dow_matrix[now.dayOfTheWeek()] );
 
  // print time
  sprintf( _buffer, "TIME: %02u:%02u:%02u", now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second() );
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(_buffer);
  // print date
  sprintf( _buffer, "DATE: %02u-%02u-%04u", now.day(), now.month(), now.year() );
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print(_buffer);
}
 

////////////////////////////////////// end RTC functions //////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////////////// DS18B20 sensor functions ///////////////////////////////////
bool ds18b20_start()
{
  bool ret = 0;
  digitalWrite(DS18B20_PIN, LOW);  // send reset pulse to the DS18B20 sensor
  pinMode(DS18B20_PIN, OUTPUT);
  delayMicroseconds(500);          // wait 500 us
  pinMode(DS18B20_PIN, INPUT);
  delayMicroseconds(100);          // wait to read the DS18B20 sensor response
  if (!digitalRead(DS18B20_PIN))
  {
    ret = 1;                  // DS18B20 sensor is present
    delayMicroseconds(400);   // wait 400 us
  }
  return(ret);
}
 
void ds18b20_write_bit(bool value)
{
  digitalWrite(DS18B20_PIN, LOW);
  pinMode(DS18B20_PIN, OUTPUT);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(DS18B20_PIN, value);
  delayMicroseconds(80);
  pinMode(DS18B20_PIN, INPUT);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
}
 
void ds18b20_write_byte(byte value)
{
  byte i;
  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    ds18b20_write_bit(bitRead(value, i));
}
 
bool ds18b20_read_bit(void)
{
  bool value;
  digitalWrite(DS18B20_PIN, LOW);
  pinMode(DS18B20_PIN, OUTPUT);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  pinMode(DS18B20_PIN, INPUT);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  value = digitalRead(DS18B20_PIN);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  return value;
}
 
byte ds18b20_read_byte(void)
{
  byte i, value;
  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    bitWrite(value, i, ds18b20_read_bit());
  return value;
}
 
bool ds18b20_read(int *raw_temp_value)
{
  if (!ds18b20_start())  // send start pulse
    return(0);
  ds18b20_write_byte(0xCC);   // send skip ROM command
  ds18b20_write_byte(0x44);   // send start conversion command
  while(ds18b20_read_byte() == 0);  // wait for conversion complete
  if (!ds18b20_start())             // send start pulse
    return(0);                      // return 0 if error
  ds18b20_write_byte(0xCC);         // send skip ROM command
  ds18b20_write_byte(0xBE);         // send read command
 
  // read temperature LSB byte and store it on raw_temp_value LSB byte
  *raw_temp_value = ds18b20_read_byte();
  // read temperature MSB byte and store it on raw_temp_value MSB byte
  *raw_temp_value |= (unsigned int)(ds18b20_read_byte() << 8);
 
  return(1);  // OK --> return 1
}
```

Comment: why is the title of your post `RTC shield with LCD and Keypad` when the problem is with the SD card?

Comment: run an SD card read/write example sketch to confirm functionality